# How to Speed Up the Apriori Framework Based On to Generate Only Association Rules Which Consequents (Right Hand Side) Are One Element of the Data Set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-mining, apriori

I have a csv file with 600 000 rows and 15 columns `"Col1, Col2 ... COl15"`. I want to generate association rules where only the right hand side has only values from col15. I am using the apriori implementation from [here](https://github.com/asaini/Apriori)

It calculates the minSupport for each itemset this way :

```
oneCSet = returnItemsWithMinSupport(itemSet,
                                        transactionList,
                                        minSupport,
                                        freqSet)
    print "reached line 80"
    currentLSet = oneCSet
    k = 2
    while(currentLSet != set([])):
        print k
        largeSet[k-1] = currentLSet
        currentLSet = joinSet(currentLSet, k)
        currentCSet = returnItemsWithMinSupport(currentLSet,
                                                transactionList,
                                                minSupport,
                                                freqSet)
        currentLSet = currentCSet
        k = k + 1

def returnItemsWithMinSupport(itemSet, transactionList, minSupport, freqSet):
        """calculates the support for items in the itemSet and returns a subset
       of the itemSet each of whose elements satisfies the minimum support"""
        _itemSet = set()
        localSet = defaultdict(int)
        #print itemSet

        for item in itemSet:
            #print "I am here", list(item)


            for transaction in transactionList:
                if item.issubset(transaction):
                    freqSet[item] += 1
                    localSet[item] += 1
        print "Done half"
        for item, count in localSet.items():
            support = float(count)/len(transactionList)

            if support >= minSupport:
                _itemSet.add(item)

        return _itemSet
```

But for the many rows I have, it would take a lot of time, Since I want the RHS to be constrained to only having values from a specific column(Col15), can I make the implementation faster by somehow cutting down on the frequent itemsets? One of the other ways is to filter the rules at the end, but it would have the same time complexity. Or is there some other implementation/library which helps me speed up things?

Comment: That is **not a correct implementation of Apriori**. It misses crucial optimizations and will be *extremely* slow.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse - Ya, i am starting to implement it now using ideas from your answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @n01dea - Thanks for the editing title. This makes much more sense

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, do you know any efficient python implementation of the apriori algorithm? I tried mlxtend but it raised out of  memory error for 50 000 transaction, 5 000 items which is not considered at all as a big transaction database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Split your data set, based on the value in your column 15, which will be your right hand side RHS. So if you have 5 different values in that column, you get 5 data sets now. Remove the last column each, which is constant now.
2. Compute frequent itemsets (*not* association rules) on the other columns only, by Apriori on each *subset* (faster!). But you will still need a much better implementation than that random github version you linked. It only needs FIMs, not rules!
3. Compose frequent itemset with partition key into an association rule, (FIS -> RHS) and evaluate like an association rule with your preferred metric.

This is a lot faster, because it will *not* generate frequent itemsets that span multiple col15 keys. Within each partition, all remaining data is relevant for your objective. Plus, it works with *unmodified* Apriori FIM generation.

Comment: i do not get it. could you please give an example? i think, with this approach association rules are missing in the result which contain as antecedent frequent itemsets of the omitted column.

Comment: He doesn't want those. He wants col15 to be RHS only.

Comment: yes, only frequent itemsets of colum 15 as consequent (right handed side) of the association rules. but with this approach the result of the extraction of frequent itemets gets flawed. e.g. three transaction {(a, b), (a, c), (b)}. support is 50%. frequent itemsets are {(a), (b)}. now the third transaction would be to omitted: {(a, b), (a, c)}. no {(b)}. support again 50%. frequent itemsets are {(a)}. the frequent itemset {(b)} is now missing in the result of the extraction of the freuqent itemsets. and therefore the frequent itemset {(b)} is missing in the generation of the association rules.

Comment: I never suggested to omit the last transaction. What is column 15 in your example?

Comment: okay. now i see. op likes to have only association rules which consequents are one specific element alias column 15. not consequents which are frequent itemsets of one specific transaction. but then i think there is a smoother way to speed up the extraction of frequent itemsets. not beforehand but within the apriori framework. please see my answer for an update.

Comment: You are slowly changing your answer into mine. But note that there isn't just one value in col15. that's why I proposed step no 1.

Comment: not changing my answer slowly. not changing it into yours. please read my answer. and my answer is valid for one or multiple values for x alias column 15. if x are multiple values then just multiple 1 length frequent itemsets need to be removed if x has 1 length frequent itemsets at all. no need for a split of the data set beforehand. rather a smooth integration into the algorithm itself. and a proper stop of the algorithm if there is no association rule with x as consequent.

Comment: Partitioning the data by the last column is *way* easier than your approach. Because them you can use the *unmodified* Apriori itemset generation part and immediately have the rule candidates without any rule extraction algorithm. Plus, because of the smaller data sets, it will be several times faster, as it doesn't tentage any unwanted rule ever, and won't even count them.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anony-Mousse and @n01dea. Your discussion helped a lot in understanding apriori and ways in which i can play around with the different things i want to do with frequent itemsets and association rules.

Answer (score 2):

no. there is no way to speed up the complexity of the apriori framework in order to generate association rules with only one specific element of the data set as the consequent. however you could speed up the computing time a bit.

the apriori framework consists of two steps. first step is to generate the frequent itemsets. second step is to generate of these frequent itemsets the association rules. to speed up the framework there is little use to look into the generation of the association rules. the bulk of the complexity of the apriori algorithm lies within the extraction of the frequent itemsets.

the apriori algorithm extracts frequent itemsets in the following way:

1. uniquify all items
2. get of those uniquify items all 1 length frequent itemsets
3. combine those 1 length frequent itemsets to 2 length itemsets
4. get of those 2 length itemsets all 2 length frequent itemsets
5. combine those n length frequent itemsets to n+1 length itemsets
6. get of those n+1 itemsets all n+1 frequent itemsets
7. repeat 5. and 6. until there are no frequent itemsets to get out of the n+1 combined itemsets

of those generated n+1 length frequent itemsets the association rules are generated. the generation of the association rules is fairly simple:

1. combine the frequent itemsets to association rules
2. check the generated association rule against the confidence level
3. if the association rule lies over the confidence level it is a strong association rule and therefore a valid association rule

the element of the data set which is supposed to be the consequent of all generated association rules is in the following called x.

first step in order to speed up the computation is to cutomize step 1 the extraction of the frequent itemsets. in step 1.2 is the 1 length frequent itemset {(x)} to be removed from the result set of 1 lenght frequent itemsets. if the element is not be extacted as a frequent itemset in step 1.2 the algorithm is supposed to stop. because then there can not be association rules with the element as a consequent. an association rule consists of n length frequent itemsets.

therefore the result of step 1 the extraction of the frequent itemsets contains only those n length frequent itemsets which are suitable to be an antecedent for an association rule which consequent can only be {(x)}. these are those frequent itemsets which does not contain {(x)}. and this saves computational time because there is one 1 length frequent itemset less of which are n length itemsets are to be combined and to be checked against the support level if the itemset is a frequent itemset.

second step in order to speed up the computation is to cutomize step 2 the generation of the association rules. in step 2.1 are only association rules to be generated which have as the consequent {(x)}. the assoction can be formed like take the result of the frequent itemsets extraction and combine each frequent itemset as the antecedent with {(x)} as the consequent to an association rule. therefore an association rule would like ({(n length frequent itemset)} -> {(x)}).

but to really speed up the computation use another alorithm to extract the freuqent itemsets. the fp-growth algorithm is already a way faster. the fastest algorithm to extraxt freuquent itemsets is up to date the prepost+ algorithm.

a neat python library with algorithms to extract frequent itemsets is this [one](https://www.borgelt.net/pyfim.html).

tl;dr: complexity stays the same. computing time can be improved. overall another faster algorithm should be used instead of the apriori like the fp-growth.

Comment: Actually, there is a way to do this much faster, because the "target" column has always only one value. See my answer.

Comment: if the approch of the answer would work, i do not see how this approch would be much faster? please see my comment to your answer. as far as i understand your answer, the suggestion is to omit within the creation of the frequent itemsets the one specific coulmn op mentioned. besides that i think that this approach would miss out association rules in the result, the complexity time would be the same. that he should use another algorithm to extract frequent itemsets is out of question as i stated as well.

Comment: It will be much faster because of the partitions, and because it no longer will find frequent itemsets without a value in the last column.

Comment: the omitting of one column would it speed up just a tiny bit. the complexity stays the same. and that only frequent itemsets would be extracted that did not include the elements of the omitted column would lead to a false result. please see my comment to your answer.

Comment: That "tiny" bit can be quite large. Because he has long transactions (always 15 columns!). It reduces the average length of transactions by 1, and usually the number of candidates by 2x. And the partitioning further helps.

Comment: If you remove the 1-length itemsets from col15, Apriori-gen will *not* generate any 2-length itemsets with x either (pruning!) so you just destroyed the results: you completely wiped out that column with your modification. At the same time, you continue to generate frequent sets involving different col15 values. I.e. useless work. **See my suggestion for something much simpler, that actually works**.